# How to work with Identity when already created User and Role table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am doing a project for learning purpose. I have already created User and Role tables. Is it possible to work with inbuilt Role based authorization and authentication with these tables? Or do I have to create all things (including Role table) provided by MVC?

Comment: It'll be easier to create Identity tables and move the data over to the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Identity provided tables as asp.net identity code depends on certain columns being available in these tables and the identity manager classes (usermanager, rolemanager) are written such that they depend on the Identity tables being available. Identity will provide you more tables than only users and roles (claims, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Identity will create all the tables for you if they don't exist. You don't need to create them yourself. 
It will depend on your connection string as to where these files are created.

Identity creates:
__MigrationHistory,
AspNetRoles,
AspNetUserClaims,
AspNetUserLogins,
AspNetUserRoles,
AspNetUsers

Answer (score 0):

If you have somehow created an SQL database, which have the structure, the Identity requires, you can just specify a connection string to it in your Web.config file instead of the default one.